# Optimise sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, time

I have got query taking up to 40 secs to execute and I was wondering how to make it faster...

```
SELECT rp.`id` as rip,r.`id`, 
  rl.`id` as rlid, r.`number`, r.`type`, 
  a.`title` as atitle, a.`id` as aid, more, 
  more_valid 
FROM 
  `R_l_p` rp INNER JOIN 
  `Rl` rl ON rp.`rl_id` = rl.`id` INNER JOIN 
  `R` r ON r.`id` = rl.`r_id` INNER JOIN 
  `A` a ON a.`id` = r.`a_id` 
  LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT `type`, `v`, `r_id`, COUNT(*) AS more 
    FROM `R_l` 
    WHERE `type` = 'stream' AND `v` = 1 
    GROUP BY `r_id`) stm ON stm.`r_id` = r.`id`
  LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT `type`, `v`, `r_id`, COUNT(*) AS more_valid 
    FROM `R_l` 
    WHERE `type` = 'stream' AND `v` = 0 
    GROUP BY `r_id`) morelink ON morelink.`r_id` = r.`id`
WHERE rp.`link` = 'dead' AND rl.`type` = 'stream' 
ORDER BY rip ASC 
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

```
+-----+--------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+-------------+----------+---------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id  | select_type  |    table      |  type   |      possible_keys       |    key      | key_len  |           ref             | rows   |                    Extra                     |
+-----+--------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+-------------+----------+---------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1  | PRIMARY      | r             | ALL     | PRIMARY,a_id             | NULL        | NULL     | NULL                      | 21804  | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  1  | PRIMARY      | a             | eq_ref  | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY     | 4        | db453988339.r.a_id        |     1  |                                              |
|  1  | PRIMARY      | rl            | ref     | PRIMARY,r_id,type        | r_id        | 4        | db453988339.r.id          |     1  | Using where                                  |
|  1  | PRIMARY      | derived2      | ALL     | NULL                     | NULL        | NULL     | NULL                      | 21077  |                                              |
|  1  | PRIMARY      | derived3      | ALL     | NULL                     | NULL        | NULL     | NULL                      |     1  |                                              |
|  1  | PRIMARY      | rp            | eq_ref  | rl_id                    | rl_id       | 4        | db453988339.rl.id         |     1  | Using where                                  |
|  3  | DERIVED      | R_link        | ALL     | type                     | NULL        | NULL     | NULL                      | 27580  | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2  | DERIVED      | R_link        | ALL     | type                     | NULL        | NULL     | NULL                      | 27580  | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+-----+--------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+-------------+----------+---------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Thank you :)

Comment: how does your query perform when you remove those 2 left joins?

Comment: what is the point of the left joins? you're not referring to them anywhere

Comment: he's using the more and more_valid from the left joins as results of the select clause

Comment: is it the v column bit? Or there are different results for the R_l table?

Comment: @Leo, it performs really well without the two left join (0.04secs).. but I really need these.. FuzzyTree, more and more_valid are coming from these two left join

Comment: @cloud1250000 then these left joins are your bottleneck. They're performing costly operations (count + group by). You must try to rewrite them (but I don't know what I can suggest you in order to do that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one thing, I'd replace the two inline views with a single inline view, return `more` and `more_valid` from the same inline view by moving the conditions from the WHERE clause into expressions in the SELECT list), and eliminating the `more_link` view.

I'd modify the `stm` inline view to be something like this:

```
       ( SELECT q.r_id
              , SUM(q.v=1) AS `more`
              , SUM(q.v=0) AS `more_valid`
           FROM `R_l` q
          WHERE q.type = 'stream'
          GROUP BY q.r_id
       ) stm
```

I'd also provide a covering index to optimize that inline view query, for example:

```
    CREATE INDEX R_1_IX1 ON R_1 (type, r_id, v)
```

With the equality predicate on the leading column `type`, MySQL may be able to optimize the GROUP BY operation using the index (avoiding a "using filesort" operation). We'd prefer to see "Using index" in the extra column of the explain.

Unfortunately, the derived table will not be indexed. But at least with this change, you're only materializing one inline view, avoids an extra join operation.

---

That is, I'd replace these two lines:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `type`, `v`, `r_id`, COUNT(*) AS more FROM `R_l` WHERE `type` = 'stream' AND `v` = 1 GROUP BY `r_id`) stm ON stm.`r_id` = r.`id`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `type`, `v`, `r_id`, COUNT(*) AS more_valid FROM `R_l` WHERE `type` = 'stream' AND `v` = 0 GROUP BY `r_id`) morelink ON morelink.`r_id` = r.`id`
```

With this:

```
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT q.r_id
              , SUM(q.v=1) AS `more`
              , SUM(q.v=0) AS `more_valid`
           FROM `R_l` q
          WHERE q.type = 'stream'
          GROUP BY q.r_id
       ) stm
    ON stm.r_id =  r.id
```

Comment: I should add the index even if I already have one for type, r_id and v?

Comment: From 40secs to 2secs it's way better. Thank you

Comment: @cloud1250000: The "Using filesort" operation can be expensive, especially on large sets. It's sometimes possible to get MySQL to avoid that operation, and make use of an index. (When the rows that need to be "grouped" together are contiguous in the index, MySQL can get the result without materializing the rows; when the query can be satisified from just the index, without a lookup of into the data pages of the underlying table, that's called a "covering" index, and we'll see "Using index" in the EXPLAIN output. But, the join to that derived table is still going to be expensive.

Comment: @cloud1250000: NOTE: the change I suggested may return a NULL instead of a 0 for `more` and/or `more_valid`, or may return a zero instead of a NULL. (I was thinking it would, then I decided it wouldn't; I'm not sure about it now. Won't cost anything to use `IFNULL(SUM(q.v=1),0)` to get it to return a 0 instead of a NULL. You could still get a NULL in the outer query if there were no matching rows, you could just as easily `IFNULL(more,0) AS more` in the outer query.

Comment: Okay now it's really not bad at all. Thank you ;) I've added the index and all. It's working great :)

Comment: it's now returning a 0, before it was a NULL need to change some code to deal with it :) but thank you for this again :)